# Using a gRPC Interceptor with an Armeria server

Tags: grpc, grpc-java, armeria

I'm porting an existing gRPC server to use the Armeria framework and I have a class that implements io.grpc.ServerInterceptor that I would like to use.  Is that possible?

If not, how do I provide similar behavior to the [TransmitStatusRuntimeExceptionInterceptor](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/util/TransmitStatusRuntimeExceptionInterceptor.html) class which logs errors and returns the details to the client?